# jquery как заставить скрипт заново считать элементы страницы без перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, возникла у меня проблема, у меня на страничке есть таблица, при нажатии на строчку таблицы должна выполняться функция, проблема в том, что я с помощью другой функции добавляю новую строку в таблицу, и вот уже для этой новой функции не работает клик, пробовал дублировать код клика, но тогда для старых записей будет функция отрабатывать несколько раз.
Теперь к сути вопроса: возможно сделать так чтобы скрипт считал заново все элементы страницы, без её перезагрузки?

Функция которая должна запускаться

```js
 function shop_show(idShop){

  $.ajax({
   url: '../modules/shop_admin.php',
   data:{
    id_shop: idShop
   },
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data){

    data = data.substr(1, data.length);
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    console.log(json);

   }

  });
  
 }
```

Функция которая добавляет новую строку в таблицу

function new_srt_table_shop(data_new_shop, json){

```
        $('#shop_table').append('<tr class="srt_table_shop"></tr>');
        var new_str = $('#shop_table').find('tbody tr:last-child');

        new_str.html('<td class="shop_id">' + json['id'] + '</td><td class="shop_address">' + data_new_shop['name'] + '</td><td class="shop_phone">' + data_new_shop['phone'] + '</td>');

        // Открытие настроек магазина с помощзью таблицы

        $('.srt_table_shop').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css(cursorCSS);
        });

    }
```

Функция которая просто запускается при нажатии на строку таблицы

```js
 $('.srt_table_shop').click(function(){

  var idShop = $(this).children('.shop_id').text();

  shop_show(idShop);

 });
```

Comment: Умоляю, хоть немного кода!

Comment: Используйте `$(document).on("click", ".class-of-row", function(e){ ... });`

Comment: я скинул, посомтри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#shop_table').on('click', '.srt_table_shop', function(){
  var idShop = $(this).children('.shop_id').text();
  shop_show(idShop);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @КонстантинСтрамаус На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.